# Is there an easy way to slant / angled dividers in TextGrid or Grid?

Tags: graphics, grid-layouts, display

Is there an easy way to add angled dividers in `TextGrid` or `Grid`.

Consider the following:

[image]

One fake way would be to use the following function.

```
angledDivider[text1_,text2_]:=Graphics[{
    {
        Directive[Thick,White],
        InfiniteLine[{{-1,1},{1,-1}}]
    },
    {
        Text[Style[text1,Directive[Bold,White,FontSize->11]],{-0.42,-0.4}],
        Text[Style[text2,Directive[Bold,White,FontSize->11]],{0.42,0.4}]
    }
},PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1}},ImageSize->{70,70},Background->Gray,ImagePadding->None];
```

I can then add these graphics in positions in `TextGrid` using function:

```
TextGrid[{
    {angledDivider[...,...],...},
    ...
},
    Frame->All,
    FrameStyle->Directive[Thick,White],
    Background->{{},{},{...}},
    ItemStyle->{{{...},{},{...}},
    ItemSize->0,
    Alignment->{Center,Center},
    Spacings->{{3->0.25,4->0.15,5->0},{3->0.25,4->0.15,5->0}}
];
```

But the problem is it requires manual adjustment of text inside `angledDivider`. Is there a way to automatically wrap text inside these `angledDivider`.

Also once I put the `angledDivider` inside `TextGrid` it creates space between the boundary of the `Graphics` and the `Frame` of the `TextGrid`. This requires again manual control of `Spacings`.

Looking for a better way to add angled dividers in a `TextGrid` or `Grid`.